# Does independence of each $Y, Z$ from $ X$ imply independence of $f(Y,Z)$ from $X$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm trying to figure out a proof for the following statement.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and $X$ and $Z$ are independent,

then $X$ and $f(Y,Z)$ are also independent, for any $f(\cdot, \cdot)$

Is there any counter-example against the above statement?

Comment: Are you sure you've got the right definition of independence there? It looks like what you wrote would hold for $X=Y$, pretty much the exact opposite of independence.

Comment: @Chessanator Oh, I just scribbled my own knowledge of independence, so I just edited. By the way, is there any concise way of defining independence?

Comment: @moreblue two random variables are independent if their joint law is a product measure? Not more concise than just writing it out

Comment: a casuistical one: let $X=1$ and $Y=Z$, then $(X,Y)$ and $(X,Z)$ are both independent but letting $f(Y,Z)=1+Y-Z$ you have $X=f(Y,Z)$

Comment: @gt6989b that's OK though isn't it? $P(X\in A \cup F(Y,Z)\in A) = P(X\in A )P( F(Y,Z)\in A) = \begin{cases} 1 & 1 \in A \\ 0 & 1\notin A \end{cases}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be three binary random variables such that all valuations in which an even number of them are $1$ are equiprobable (and the other valuations don't occur). Then $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and $X$ and $Z$ are independent, but $X=Y\operatorname{XOR} Z$.

Answer (score 3):

I like this question. Your statement sounds very credible AND is wrong. One cannot see enough examples of statements like that!

I like Joriki's counterexample. Here is another one. I throw a die, the outcome is A. We take $X$ to be the event $A \in \{1, 2, 3\}$, $Y$ is the event that $A \in \{1, 5\}$ and $Z$ is the event that $A \in \{1, 6\}$.

Now the probability that $Y$ holds given $X$ is 1/3, which is also the probability that $Y$ holds without any knowledge of whether or not $X$ is true. So $X$ and $Y$ are independent. (You can also see it from the other side: the probability that $X$ holds is a priori 1/2. After knowing $Y$ it is still 1/2. So $X$ and $Y$ are independent.)

The reasoning that $X$ and $Z$ are independent is identical.

Now let $f(X, Y)$ is $X$ AND $Y$. Tracing back the definition we find that $f(X, Y)$ is the event $A = 1$. This is clearly not independent of $X$ intuitively, and this intuition is backed up by computation: the probability of $X$ is 1/2 without any knowledge of $f(X, Y)$ but becomes 1 once we know that $f(X, Y)$ is true.